# Unable to assign property AnimationId. Content expected, got nil

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

I don't know what's happening, but i'm getting that error in output. Apparently every animations of the Anims table and normalcombo table exists, and the property too. I tested it in Commandbar but didn't work. I don't know how to fix it and don't know what's the problem. Please help me. Code below:

--Local Script

```
local Replicated = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local UIS = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local Remote = Replicated.CombateEvent
local Player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local Char = Player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
local Humanoid = Char:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local istoolequipped = false
script.Parent.Equipped:Connect(function()
    istoolequipped = true
end)
script.Parent.Unequipped:Connect(function()
    istoolequipped = false
end)
local lastM1Time = 0
local lastM1End = 0
local combo = 1
local canAir = true
local Anims = {
    "rbxassetid://12270296026",
    "rbxassetid://12290262661",
    "rbxassetid://12290234803",
}
local normalcombo = {
    "rbxassetid://12303443278",
    "rbxassetid://12303443278",
    "rbxassetid://12303527113",
    "rbxassetid://12303770582"
}
function hb(size, cframe, ignore, char)
    local hitbox = Instance.new("Part", workspace)
    hitbox.Size = size
    hitbox.CFrame = cframe
    hitbox.Anchored = true
    hitbox.CanCollide = false
    hitbox.Transparency = .6
    hitbox.Name = "hb"
    hitbox.Material = Enum.Material.ForceField
    hitbox.CanQuery = false
    local connection
    connection = hitbox.Touched:Connect(function()
        connection:Disconnect()
    end)
    local lasttarget
    for _, v in pairs(hitbox:GetTouchingParts()) do
        if v.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") and table.find(ignore, v.Parent.Name) == nil then
            if lasttarget then
                if (lasttarget.Position - char.PrimaryPart.Position).Magnitude > (v.Position - char.PrimaryPart.Position).Magnitude then
                    lasttarget = v.Parent.PrimaryPart
                end
            else
                lasttarget = v.Parent.PrimaryPart
            end
        end
    end
    hitbox:Destroy()
    if lasttarget then
        return lasttarget.Parent
    else
        return nil
    end
end
UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(input, istyping)
    if istyping then return end
    if input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1 and tick() - lastM1Time > .3 and tick() - lastM1End > .7 and istoolequipped then
        if tick() - lastM1Time > .7 then
            combo = 0
        end
        lastM1Time = tick()
        local animation = Instance.new("Animation", workspace.Animation)
        local air = nil
        if UIS:IsKeyDown("Space") and canAir == true and combo == 2 then
            canAir = false
            air = "Up"
            animation.AnimationId = Anims[1]
        elseif UIS:IsKeyDown("Space") and combo == 3 and not canAir then
            air = "Down"
            animation.AnimationId = Anims[2]
        else
            animation.AnimationId = normalcombo[combo]
        end
        local load = Humanoid:LoadAnimation(animation)
        load:Play()
        animation:Destroy()
        local hitTarg = hb(Vector3.new(3,5,3), Char.PrimaryPart.CFrame * CFrame.new(0,0,-3), {Char}, Char)
        local Info = {
            ["Target"] = hitTarg,
            ["Combo"] = combo,
            ["Character"] = Char,
            ["Air"] = air
        }
        Remote:FireServer("Combo", Info)
        if combo == #normalcombo then
            combo = 1
            lastM1End = tick()
        else
            combo += 1
        end
        Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 0
        task.wait(.4)
        Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 16
    end
end)
```

The error send me to this line: "`animation.AnimationId = normalcombo[combo]`"

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that `normalcombo[combo]` is returning nil when it should be a content url. That means that `combo` isn't a value between 1 and #normalcombo (4).

The only place where that could be is here :

```lua
        if tick() - lastM1Time > .7 then
            combo = 0
        end
```

Here you are resetting the combo counter, but you set it too low. Arrays in lua are 1-indexed. You need to set it to :

```lua
            combo = 1
```